# python how to drop values from an array that dont fit in a range

Tags: python, arrays

So I have an array with thousands of numbers but I want to drop the numbers that don't fall between a certain range. I tried a loop but I'm probably doing it wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
query_result = pd.read_csv('data_2.csv')
query_result
parallax = query_result['parallax']

parallax_range = []
for i in parallax:
    if parallax[i]>= 1:
        np.append(parallax_range)
    elif parallax[i]<=1.3:
        np.append(parallax_range)
```

Comment: `parallax` is empty. The loop never executes.

Comment: Now `parallax` is undefined, as is `np`. This is not a [mre].

Comment: parallax is not empty data is in txt file. np is also defined just didnt put it here

Comment: Parallax is indeed undefined in the question, and while I assume `np` is an alias for `numpy` it's unreasonable to expect users to assume things about or fill in the blanks in the code, _and_ expect high quality answers. Please take the [tour] and read how to create a [mre] in order to understand what SO expects. Please accept my answer if it's correct, upvote it if it's helped you, and comment it if it needs work.

Comment: parallax is a list that has 5507 elements. your solution didn't work but i was able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

The for-loop iterates over elements in `parallax` but then uses these values as indexes for random access.

```py
for i in parallax:
    if parallax[i]...
```

Here, `i` is a value in `parallax`, not the index of the value. Use this instead:

```py
for i in parallax:
        if i...
```

There's still a problem with the logic, it will put all values greater than or equal to 1, and all values less than 1 into `parallax_range`, i.e all values.

for-loop implementation:

```py
parallax_range = []
for i in parallax:
    if 1 <= i <= 1.3:
         parallax_range.append(i)
```

This is simple enough for a list comprehension:

```py
parallax_range = [i for i in parallax if 1 <= i <= 1.3]
```

Yet another way:

```py
def in_range(n):
    return 1 <= n <= 1.3

parallax_range = list(filter(in_range, parallax))
```

The `filter()` function returns an iterator rather than a `list` which can be preferable in some circumstances. If you don't know that yours is one of those circumstances just use `for` or the comprehension.